# mysql update view automatically when related table structure changed ?

Tags: php, mysql, view

I have table _house with field 'soft_delete' default is 0.

Then I have a View to check undeleted entries, hence I have

```
CREATE VIEW house AS 
SELECT * FROM _house where soft_delete = 0;
```

But the problem now is that everytime I modify table _house, I'll need to re-update my view so that is not broken. 
So each time after modify table _house, I execute

```
ALTER VIEW house AS 
SELECT * FROM _house where soft_delete = 0;
```

I wanted to find an easier way to execute above alter script, so I tried to create a procedure/function with 'alter view' inside, but mysql seems to prohibit me doing that.

## Question :

- Any other solution to simplify this 'redundant' actions ?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to alter the table at all? In most cases that's a sign of not well done database design. A database design should be fix, no changes later (except during development).

Comment: Yes, I'm still in development. Its a big database and my client keep adding features and stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

`The view definition is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition. For example, if a view is defined as SELECT * on a table, new columns added to the table later do not become part of the view.`

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419915/refresh-mysql-views)

Comment: I'm quite new in here.... just wanted to tell that there is no simple way to do that.

Comment: @jaczes Yes, I knew that. Thx anyway.